# Not able to see the image on non IE browser

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

We have one webpage where clicking on "add More" link provides me an input box along with one "Delete" button image, named as 'delImg'. While clicking on "addMore" link, i am successfully able to add one textbox along with delete image on IE browsers. But the same thing is not working on Mozilla/Chrome. I can see only the textbox and the delete button is not visible at all.

Can anyone please tell me what is the issue with non IE browser.

CSS Code for IE CSS file :-

```
span.delImg
{
height:25px;
width:17px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 1px;
background: url(../../img/icons/icn_Delete.png) no-repeat;
}
```

CSS Code for non IE CSS file:-

```
span.delImg
{
height:25px;
width:17px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 1px;
background: url("../img/icons/icn_Delete.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Javascript code :-

```
var addMore = function() {
var numAdd = $("#emails > div").length;
       if (numAdd >= 10)

    return;

$('#emails').append("<div> <input type='text' class='GMtradeSearch' size='80' /> <span class='delImg' onclick='deleteMail(this);'/></div>");

    }
```

Please help.

Comment: you sure about the image paths? I can see diff paths
background: url(../../img/icons/icn_Delete.png) no-repeat;
} and 
background: url(../img/icons/icn_Delete.png) no-repeat;
}

Comment: pls check your image paths in both CSS they are different

Comment: that's how we are dipalying it for other images in non IE browser. The issue got fixed by adding below comment :    display:inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

A span usually has a display of "inline" Since there is no text inside the span this means it will take up no space on your UI. So there is not space to display the image. Change the span's display to inline-block.

```
span.delImg
{
height:25px;
width:17px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 1px;
background: url("image.png") no-repeat;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @ user3589536
Thank you so much. you have saved my time :)